# Base tag changes domain name to the site in root

Tags: html

I have multiple sites in my hosting stored with the following folder structure:

```
ROOT-FOLDER - SITE1 example.com
 SUB-FOLDER - SITE2 another-example.com
```

On the site in sub-folder I used html base tag in order to take advantage of relative links, however I faced some issues. The problem is that if I open the second site by its domain name it loads with the same name, but when I navigate any link it replaces the site's domain name with the one in root.

So, if any link clicked on the site, instead of getting following in address bar:

```
another-example.com/page1.php
```

I get this:

```
example.com/SITE2/page1.php
```

Could you please explain how to solve the issue?

P.S. the base tag look like this:

```
<base href="http://example.com/site2/" />
```

Comment: That's the *point* of `<base>`. Why are you using it if you don't want that?

Comment: no information given on how you set the domain to go to that folder also.

Comment: I am using it to have relative links, but it changes the domain name. Should it be like that?

Comment: @EmilGurbanov — You're using it to have links that are relative to **that URL** with that domain name, so yes, it should do that.

Comment: domain is pointer to the sub-folder  "subdirectory/site2/"

Comment: @EmilGurbanov — So what? The base element says that URLs should be relative to `http://example.com/site2/`.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, I just needed to change http://example.com/site2/ to  / in order to make it work as expected. Thanks for answers.